# Application Sharing limitations in UCMA 3.0 Contact Center sample application

Tags: lync-2010, lync, ucma

Let me preface this by saying that I know the ContactCenter sample is just a sample and that the application sharing extension classes it exposes are not officially supported.

With that said, I've found several limitations to the ContactCenter sample's application sharing functionality.

Namely:

1) After the caller shares their screen with the agent, the agent cannot take control of the caller's screen. There is no error, but the request for control just kind of happens with no result, even if the customer has set the session to accept all requests for control

2) Prior to the caller sharing their screen, the only participant in the conference they can see is the contact center attendant. As soon as the agent accepts the sharing session, the agent's identity is revealed in the caller's participant list.

3) If the caller shares their screen, closes the sharing session, then starts a new one, this new sharing session comes into the agent as a seperate conversation, in its own window with its own toast message, etc.

I have plenty of theories as to why these limitations exist and possible workarounds, but before pursuing them too aggressively, wanted to see if anybody else had workarounds OR just as usefully, if the UCMA team is confident that these are just inherent limitations to UCMA.

Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague and I found some answers, which he posted about at: http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/02/06/handling-application-sharing-calls-ucma/

The short version is that if you separate the application sharing call into another conversation and back to back it, you can get some good, basic functionality going.

Comment: Hi Peter: did you manage to get anywhere with limitation number 2? We're finding the same problem here: joining a conference using back-to-back audio works fine, but then back-to-back app sharing in a conference seems to expose the conference participants to the caller. Using a new conversation (even a new impersonation) doesn't help. I read Michael's blog post but didn't find anything specifically to do with this point. Any info you have would be much appreciated.